# Temporary files are not removing automatically

Tags: 8.0, lumia, settings

In my `Storage Check` settings, there is more than 300 MBs of temporary files since last month. I manually cleared and cleared IE cache, but it's not going below than 315 MB till this moment. There's no pending download or installation at this moment. How can I clear this memory?

Answer (score 2):

In the normal operation of the phone, it will require small amounts of space for temporary files, which is what you're seeing.

Although you can clear it via **Storage Check**, as the phone is still active it's probably using some of those temporary files, so not all can be deleted.

The **GDR2** update, which should reach all Lumia Windows Phone 8 devices by the end of September, does help to reduce the number of temporary and 'other' files left behind.

I checked two Lumia's both running GDR2...

- Lumia 820 - 12mb temporary files
- Lumia 920 - 14mb temporary files

There are also various Windows Phone related news sites which have reported that GDR2 does seem to help or correct the issue...

- [Windows Phone 8 + GDR2: Fix for "Other" Storage Bug](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-gdr2-fix-other-storage-bug)
- [Does Windows Phone 8 GDR2 fix the ‘Other Storage’ issue?](http://www.wpcentral.com/does-windows-phone-8-gdr2-fix-other-storage-issue)

Comment: Mine is Lumia 620 and I can't find the update you mentioned.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/), all devices should get the update by the end of the month.

Comment: I'm from India using Vodafone as operator(not pre-loaded). But [Nokia](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/wp8-availability-in-asia-pacific/) giving the information that Amber update for Nokia Lumia 620 is available in this region.

Comment: Look in Settings > About > Carrier - what does it say?

Comment: OS Version : 8.0.10211.204
Firmware revision number : 1030.6407.1308.0001

Comment: The line should be above that, I'm looking for the carrier/OEM info - my Lumia 820 says **CV GB** which means the phone is from the UK, so I check their list to see when I'm getting the update.

Comment: My phone is not with pre-loaded operator.

Comment: It will still have **Carrier** info. CV GB means Country Variant (aka SIM free).

Comment: I think you're expecting third entry in [this](http://cdn.wpcentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2013/07/Windows_Phone_GDR2.jpg).
Nop, there's no such information. There are only 13 entries under Phone Information.

Comment: Oh ok - well hopefully you'll get the update at the end of the month.

Comment: I put this as a new question [Where's Lumia Amber update?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/wheres-lumia-amber-update)