# Where's Lumia Amber update?

Tags: 8.0, amber-update, gdr-2, nokia-lumia-620

I'm using Nokia Lumia 620, India, No Sim. [Nokia](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/wp8-availability-in-asia-pacific/) says that update is available. But my phone is showing that it's up to date.

Comment: There is a possibility, that update is already installed, and you just haven't noticed it. Amber install (at least for me) was silent. Look in settings, if you have Glance option, for example.

Comment: Seriously, I'm eagerly waiting for this update, I'm checking current version everyday. So, no chance for silent update. And Nokia's Smart Cam only work with Amber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, [Nokia has a website which lists the status of the Amber update on all of its Windows Phone 8 devices](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/).

Even if the update status for your device is 'Available', not everyone gets the update at once. So, you have a few options...

1. Wait a couple more weeks by which time the update should appear.
2. Find your local Nokia Service Center (Care Point) and have it updated there.
3. Skip the queue and update your device manually using **Nokia Software Updater for Retail** - but this will **wipe** your device!

I won't link to *Nokia Software Updater for Retail*, but it's easy enough to find using your favourite search engine.

Comment: Is _Nokia Software Updater for Retail_ official?

Comment: Yes, but it's not supposed to be available to members of the public ;)

Comment: @NK And probably it is not a supported method.

Comment: I checked with it. But showing a minor update. No Amber update is available

Comment: Amber/GDR2 is 8.0.10328.78 btw.

Comment: It showing an update available : `1030.6407.1308.0002`. Firmware version I think. Not showing OS version.

Comment: In India, the OTA update has been released so far for .0002 firmware. Sadly most of the Lumia 620 users (including me) have older firmware. I flashed my device using NSU first and received the OS update

Comment: Why didn't we get update notification when `1030.6407.1308.0002` has released?

Comment: That's a minor firmware update (as opposed to OS update) which probably fixes a very rare bug, so devices are only updated by Care Centers when the issue is reported by a user. Bigger OS/firmware updates include all these fixes.

Comment: Yahoo!!! I got the minor update `1030.6407.1308.0002` followed by the major update (It might be `Amber`). Downloading major update now :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! you could sign up for the GDR3 Preview if you want, it's available now.

Comment: It is shown that amber software is available for lumia 620 in Nepal but my phone doesn't get any update how can i get amber software in my lumia 620

Comment: @RanjanRajKharel please start a new question, this has already been answered and accepted.