# Increasing Others Storage Memory

Tags: 8.0, storage, gdr-3, nokia-lumia-620

When I was updated to ***GDR-3*** and all my applications were re-installed the ***Others*** in ***Storage Check*** was around *600 MB*. But last week I uninstalled a game of 800 MB and streamed videos. After a day the ***Others*** found as *1.4 GB*!!! (Still after cleaning temporary files via ***Phone Storage***, ***Storage Check*** and ***Browser***). Is there any way to get back the lost space?

Similar issue was faced in GDR-1 : [Temporary files are not removing automatically](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2262/1282)

Comment: Just noticed I have 1.9 in `Other` but I'm in `GDR-2`.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled application do consume memory(sometimes). Some uninstalled application data are stored in the folder

*SDcard/Phone -> WPSystem -> Apps -> WindowsApps -> Deleted*

These contents are shown in Storage sense under **other** category. The system should automatically free the contents after a specific period of time. You can also delete it manually(not recommended).

**Warning : Editing a system folder may cause your phone not to work. Proceed with extreme caution.**

These folders are visible if when you connect your SDcard to Linux(see picture below). You can delete unwanted files from there. This is not recommended. It is wise to wait until the your phone clears the files automatically.

[image: Screenshot of Deleted apps folder]

Note : The folders will not be visible when you connect your Windows phone as a Media device. Use a SDcard reader or connect your phone as a Storage device.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have updated to GDR3, there sure is a way to get back the lost space.

1. Go to `settings` > `phone storage` and then tap `phone`
2. You will see something like this, click on the circled area

   [image]
3. Once again, click on the circled area:

   [image]

Any space that can be cleared up will be done through this method. For now, this is your best shot.

Remember, Windows Phone 8.1 is not far away :)

Comment: Please read the question properly. I clearly stated that **cleaning temporary files via Phone Storage** didn't give any positive result.