# Temporary file on opening .xap file and can't recover

Tags: 8.1-update-1, storage-check

I opened .xap file using File app, but nothing happened just lost size of app from phone memory. It's showing as temporary files in Storage Check. Tried clean that up with Storage Check and Storage Sense. Nothing happened. Is there any way to recover it?

May be this one is a related to [Temporary files are not removing automatically](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/temporary-files-are-not-removing-automatically)

Comment: Where did you get the XAP from? Was it one downloaded from the Windows Store, or "somewhere else"?

Comment: @RowlandShaw From the Windows Phone Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the same .xap file again and wait till error message shows. It will overwrite the previous temporary entry and it will automatically clean up the last one whenever the error message shows.